# Move all apps in tablet to sd card

Tags: android, android-layout

I would like to move all apps in android tablet to sd card. Can somebody give directions and sample code how to move all installed apps to sd card? I am moving these apps to sd card because we have a space problem in tablet hard disk.

Thanks,
Venkat Dayam

Answer (score 2):

The user can do this via Settings > Applications. You cannot script it.

Comment: i need to do this programatically when i found the apps that can be movable to sd card.

Comment: @kirankumar: What you want is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add this line - ***android:installLocation="auto"*** in  your application manifest file

Follow the link: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/install-location.html